# CSS Grid of Hexagons - changing the hover animation

Tags: css, animation, hover

So I found a resource for a responsive grid of hexagons with images. Does anyone know how to change the hover animations in the same coding? I'm trying to change it to a simple horizontal tile flip hover animation without changing the existing code as much as possible, Thanks!

My repository : [https://github.com/MargauxShraiman/bellashraiman/](http://github.com/MargauxShraiman/bellashraiman/)
Original website : [https://github.com/web-tiki/responsive-grid-of-hexagons](http://github.com/web-tiki/responsive-grid-of-hexagons)
the animation I'd like to imitate: https://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php

```
    /*** HOVER EFFECT ************************************************/
    .hexLink:hover h1, .hexLink:focus h1,
    .hexLink:hover p, .hexLink:focus p{
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        -ms-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
    }
```

Comment: Unsuccessfully maybe, but what have you tried so far? And define `change`. Change to what?

Comment: I've been looking at the css code and how he organizes his JS but i can't figure out what command controls the animation ... if that makes sense. I want to change it to a simple flip like the one seen here : https://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php

Comment: *** HOVER EFFECT  **********************************************************************/
.hexLink:hover h1, .hexLink:focus h1,
.hexLink:hover p, .hexLink:focus p{
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
      -ms-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
          transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
}

Comment: Yeah, that's the place. But `change`, change to what?

Comment: . I want to change it to a simple flip like the one seen here : https://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php

Comment: Well, edit your question, post your code and your attempts and we'll see what we can do :)

Comment: You should reproduce 1 hexagon here and make a code snippet showing what you did to make it rotate on hover. Without that, I have made answer, but it's quite a blind guess

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

If you apply this :

```
li.hex {
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
   transition: transform .2s ease-out;
}
```

each hexagon should rotate by 180° on hover.

Comment: Well yes, you have to place another card back-to-back, as explained in David Walsh's tutorial.